# Error when installing spree_mail gem. spree_mail (= 0.40.0.4) ruby depends on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, gemfile

I'm trying to add spree_mail gem to my Spree project.

& when I run "bundle install"

I get this message:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "devise":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_mail (= 0.40.0.4) ruby depends on
      devise (= 1.2.rc) ruby

```
spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
  devise (2.2.3)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_mail (= 0.40.0.4) ruby depends on
      spree_core (= 0.30.1) ruby

```
spree_mail (= 0.40.0.4) ruby depends on
  spree_core (1.3.2)
```

my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'spree_i18n', :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git"

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', '1.3.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_mail', '0.40.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the extension specifies `spree_core >= 0.30.1` as a dependency, this will almost certainly not work with spree 1.3.2 without modification.

If you look at the [github network](https://github.com/citrus/spree_mail/network) for this gem, there may be a more up to date fork you can use. Alternatively, I'd suggest looking at using a product like [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) for your mailing list, there's at least one more up to date [extension for that](https://github.com/sbeam/spree-mail-chimp).